# Identifying a part to replace

Tags: plumbing

While investigating a minor leak under the sink I found the following cracked part.

[image: Cracked part]

I have no experience in plumbing, but I thought maybe I could still try and replace it myself. The problem is that I don't know what this part is called.

There is also a larger context if it's helpful. This pipe goes straight into my cold water tap. [image: Larger context]
I would appreciate any tips or links to guides that can be relevant.

Many thanks!

Comment: The cracking in the brass fitting could have been caused by some cleaner containing ammonia. Many cleaning products contain ammonia and it will crack brass.

Comment: Doesn't matter; that's all wonky in the first place. You need to get from 1/2" copper to 1/4" (?) copper, using compression fittings. **Do not tape or dope compression fittings**, or you will have to tighten them until they break.... Prob need a short piece of either 1/2" or 1/4", that's a little longer than what's there, or not, depending on the developed length of your new fittings.

Comment: There's supposed to be a valve there to make this transition not so stupid... Which come as 1/2" compression to either 3/8" or 1/4". - What's on the far other end of that sharkbite? Something that would take a braided connector coming from a valve and be done in five min?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a 3/4 female to 3/8 male adaptor.

Either measure and go shopping or take it apart and go shopping.